# "Innocent truth" usage in the sentence

Tags: word-choice

Can I say "innocent truth" in the following sentence and isn't it better to use "our" before "lifetime" instead of the article.

> "He was not faithful. It was not  **innocent truth** he was going to share. He wanted to confess at the death bed and tell his wife about his affair. Such confessions should be made during **?the** lifetime, I think."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that "innocent truth" is an example of [hypallage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypallage), wherein an abstract noun becomes personified. Truth is unchanging and factual. What is innocent or guilty of a crime or misdeed is the person who is telling the story, not the truth. So having 'innocent' modify 'truth' is not a standard usage, although the meaning does get across. As a literary device it is perfectly fine, if that is what you are aiming for.

I agree that 'during the lifetime' sounds unnatural. I would prefer 'during his lifetime' or 'during our lifetime', depending on who the speaker is.

Comment: I think "At the death bed" is also wrong. It should be ''on his deathbed."

Comment: Yes, you're right about that. I overlooked it. It should certainly be "on his deathbed".

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "It wasn't an innocent truth he was going to share." ?

Comment: I considered mentioning that too. But I think it's still correct even without the indefinite article since it is an abstract noun. Anyway, it's not the main query so I didn't include that in my answer. But I agree that "an innocent truth" sounds more natural.